# Using special characters within an AutoFilter

Tags: excel, vba

Curious if there's a simple solution to this:
Here's my AutoFilter

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("bldgops").Range.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="< 7 Days"
```

It won't work because of the "<" character.
I could replace it with:

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("bldgops").Range.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="within 7 Days"
```

and it will work fine but I'd rather be able to use the "<" character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("bldgops").Range.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="=< 7 Days"
```

to let Excel know that you are looking for the exact text `"< 7 Days"`

There is a certain amount of strangeness here. If you use the macro recorder while filtering a column which contains the text `"< 7 Days"` and do so by manually selecting the value `< 7 Days` in the filter drop-down list, the recorded macro contains code with `Criteria1 := "< 7 Days"`. But, when you "play back" the recorded code it doesn't behave the same as when you were recording it. On the other hand, if you record a macro while setting up a filter and you select the option `Text Filter` when doing so, then the recorded macro includes the equals sign in `=< 7 Days`. Perhaps this is a minor bug in the macro recorder.